# Beamer set custom fonts but not used?

Tags: beamer, fonts, fontspec

I am trying to make a template for my work at Uni.
I have set the fonts like so:

```
\setmainfont[
    Path           = uni/fonts/,
    Extension      = .otf,
    Ligatures      = TeX,
    BoldFont       = Uni-Bold,
    ItalicFont     = Uni-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = Uni-BoldItalic
]{Uni-Roman} % there is a file called uni/fonts/Uni-Roman.otf
```

I do not set the fonts elsewhere.
However, [beamer](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) does not use these fonts.
What am I doing wrong?
Yes, I import the `.sty` file.

Answer (score 0):

Beamer uses sans serif font by default. So you'll need to use `\setsansfont` instead of `\setmainfont`

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Arial} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```